# Galois theory: Gal(K/F) divides [K:F]?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and let $f(x) \in F[x]$ be defined as $f(x) = x^3 + 7x + 101$ (irreducible). Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be algebraic numbers such that $f(\alpha) = f(\beta) = f(\gamma) = 0$, but $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are not necessarily distinct. Now let $K = F(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$.

Claim 1. $[K:F] = 27$; i.e. the numbers $\alpha^a \beta^b \gamma^c$ are linearly independent for $a,b,c \in \{0,1,2\}$.

Claim 2. $|\text{Gal}(K/F)| = 6$; i.e. the set of $F$-automorphisms of $K$ are precisely those automorphisms which permute $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$, hence the number of such automorphisms is $3! = 6$.

Theorem (from textbook). $|\text{Gal}(K/F)|$ divides $[K:F]$.

Contradiction. In fact, $6$ does not divide $27$.

What went wrong here?

Comment: Your claim 1. is wrong. Indeed, although (say) $\alpha$ and $\beta$ may both be cubic over $F$, the two separate fields they generate are not “linearly disjoint”, which would have guaranteed that the compositum was of degree $9$. In fact, you’ll probably find that the compositum of two cubic fields here is of degree $6$, since the irreducible polynomial for $\beta$ over $F(\alpha)$ will turn out to be a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Hi! The problem is $[K:F]$. The elements you mentioned are not linearly independent. You have for example an upper bound for the grade that is $3!$. First add the root $\alpha$, then in $F(\alpha)[x]$ your polynomial splits in a linear factor $(x-\alpha)$ and a polynomial of degree $2$. If this polynomial is irreducible go on. Then the maximum degree is $3!$

Comment: Also how do you get $|Gal(K/F)|=6$? Have you used the discriminant?

Comment: what discriminant? how do I use it?

Comment: @atenao discriminant is a tool that tell you in a easy way (in this case) if the Galois group is a subgroup of $A_3$ or $S_3$. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) you can find the definition of it. Sostantially it works in this way: $\sqrt{disc(f)} \in \mathbb Q$ if and only if $Gal(K/\mathbb Q)$ is a subgroup of  $A_n$ ($K$ denotes the splitting field of $f$). In this case, if you compute the discriminant $(-4)(7^3) - 27(101^2)$ this is negative so its square root does not lie in $\mathbb Q$, then $Gal(F/\mathbb Q)$ is not a subgroup of $A_3$. Hence is $S_3$.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers $\alpha^a\beta^b\gamma^c$ are not necessarily linearly independent for $a,b,c\in \{0,1,2\}$.

For $F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$, a basis of this should be $\alpha^a\beta^b\gamma^c$ where $1 \le c \le [F(\gamma):F]$, $1 \le b \le [F(\gamma,\beta):F(\gamma)]$
and $1 \le a \le [F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma):F(\beta,\gamma)]$. 
So your counting of $27$ is not quite correct. In fact, over $F(\gamma)$, we 
have $x^3+7x+101=(x-\gamma)(x^2+mx+n)$ so $\beta$ is root of polynomial $x^2+mx+n$ so $[F(\beta,\gamma):F(\gamma)]\le 2$.

Comment: If $\beta = \gamma$ then $[F(\beta,\gamma) : F(\gamma)] = 1$, otherwise it =2?

Comment: If $\beta \in F(\gamma)$ then it is $1$, otherwise it is $2$.